# What is the difference between real and imaginary parts of a sinusoid?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

Can somebody explain, without using complicated mathematical formulas, *what do real and imaginary parts of the sinus function represent?*
And what are relations between them?

I cannot understand why there are differences in shape when I look the spectrum. I noticed that the maximum height of green (imaginary) line is 6,6 mm on my display while the red is cca 1/2 of the green. I thought if could it simply mean that the green represents difference between maximums of the sinusoid, e.g. 25 and -25. I cannot understand why the shape of these line is such and not like the black one. Why it is mirrored? Images welcome.

This is image which I am referring to:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should get a book and read up on the subject.  Or start with wikipedia's page.  Quote: "The Fourier transform of a function of time itself is a complex-valued function of frequency, whose absolute value represents the amount of that frequency present in the original function, and whose complex argument is the phase offset of the basic sinusoid in that frequency. "

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : Hi! Didn't you see that he asks from us to explain simply, without much math.? And you tell him of Fourier transform.  He wants smth. intuitive. Unfortunately, this is what books and universitary lectures do, mathematics and mathematics, with very little intuitive explanations.

Comment: @user1141649 : but the sinus function is REAL, where do you see an imaginary part in it? Maybe you tell us more clearly how do you get an imaginary part in the sinus.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : I apologize, I didn't see the picture below, only the one above. I take back my comment.

Comment: note: the notes in the image are to height (lenght) of the lines. @user1141649: I see it in the spectrum, see the image. The green curve is imaginary and the red is real. Both diagrams are made by program generating spectrum for the sinus function with Fourier transform.

Comment: I don't understand what's what in the diagram.  In the top plot I see a red sinusoid that seems not to be strictly sin or cos.  There's a gray plot that seems to be the absolute value of the red plot.  In the lower plot I see what appears to be a Fourier transform ... is that supposed to be the F.T. of the red trace above?  Evidently the red is the real part, and the green the imaginary.  Is the black the modulus?  If I could understand the figure, I might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. The gray curve in upper plot is amplitude. The lower plot is F.T. of the sinusoid above. I am convinced that the black curve is not modulus but the result of the FT, it should be spektrum or magnitude. More explanation is here: http://lodev.org/cgtutor/fourier.html but on that page you can see more sinusoids, some including DC. Mine spectrum contains only 1 sinusoid. I am also reading another explanation on IM site in article called "Fourier Transform Processing With ImageMagick"-he uses term "magnitude" in frequency domain and writes about imaginary and real part.

Comment: From IM site: "**The Fourier Transform is founded upon the concept of complex number sinusoidal waves. What this means is that the wave is made up of two sinusoidal components, one considered 'real' and the other considered 'imaginary'**, mathematically speaking." This is the key which I need to understand, but my problem is that I don't understand the Complex numbers and did not found intuitive explanation for this. He is using the diagrams from wiki which I cannot understand.

Comment: ImageMagick: **magnitude & phase are images with no negative values**.Real & imaginary are images with negative values (HDRI version of IM needed to work with them). See this page to check how these images looks: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fourier/ So I think that the upper left area of the spectrum represents magnitude, upper right area represents phase, bottom left area represents real part and bottom right quarter represents imaginary. _Let's have image of dimensions 1x360px & make a horizontal gradient (Black-White-Black) then we got a sinus wave made by its values_

Comment: The phrase "The Fourier Transform is founded upon the concept of complex number sinusoidal waves. What this means is that the wave is made up of two sinusoidal components, one considered 'real' and the other considered 'imaginary'"  Is potentially misleading.  Perhaps that's your issue.  The FT uses the *complex exponential* $\exp(ix) = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$.  Note that the original trace cannot be expressed as a sum of sines.  cosines are necessary, too.  These two are encoded in the a single function, the complex exponential.

Comment: Yeah, I think that it is what the author from IM wanted to say that it is made of sins and cosins. Cosins are just 90° shifted sins. I can understand how the gradients in image (sinusoids) are represented in the diagrams, but still have problem to understand the F.T. from the concept of Complex numbers... So also the imaginary and real components in spectrum makes me problem to fully understand them how they work, how it was transfered in such form of curve.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It would help to have the context.  Since you are learning about FTs from scratch, you will run into problem after problem.  Correct interpretation of the DFT spectrum is not the same as it is for the continuous FT.  Intuition will fail at times.  I think @CarlWitthoft is right.  Get a book and *study* it, or find web resources.  I googled "discrete fourier transform tutorial" and got lots of hits.  [Here's one.](http://www.fourier-series.com/fourierseries2/DFT_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have found article where the Fourier transform is greatly explained:

> **The Fourier Transform produces a complex number valued output image which can be displayed with two images, either with the real and imaginary part or with magnitude and phase.**
>   In image processing, often only the magnitude of the Fourier Transform is displayed, as it contains most of the information of the geometric structure of the spatial domain image. However, if we want to re-transform the Fourier image into the correct spatial domain after some processing in the frequency domain, we must make sure to preserve both magnitude and phase of the Fourier image.

Source: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm

So the real and imaginary numbers can be negative numbers, which in digital image processing cannot be displayed. From the comments above and other sources  I came to conclusion that real and imaginary components of the Fourier Transform comprise from sinus and cosine waves. The black curve on image is magnitude, which is positive number scaled with logarithm*. * - Now, here I am not sure what the term scale exactly means. I have two possibilities: either it scales (zooms) the curve to be better visible or it shifts the curve "upwards" by adding number so that all the values are positive, not negative.

Another question stays opened: If we have 4 images / 4 sets of data, why the curve does not contain 4 curves? Probably author of the program (http://lodev.org/cgtutor/fourier.html) Joined the two components of magnitude & phase together? I don't understand his FFT algorithm that much because it differs from standard formulas:

$$G(n)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}g(x)e^{-i2 \pi \frac{n}{N}x}$$(http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/fourier_transforms/images/fft_1d_equation.jpg)

Comment: It's not worth trying to understand the FFT algorithm right now.  Maybe in the future.  It gives exactly the same result as the standard definition if the number of points is a power of two.  (Most FFT implementations can handle set sizes that are not powers of two, but that' a different story.)  Note that there is one thing that you will have to deal with before too long.  When a computer calculates a Fourier Transform, it's actually the [*Discrete Fourier Transform*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)  that it calculates.  (Fourier analysis is a big subject ...)

Comment: It's good to understand both algorithms but I will need FFT for my project not DFT, because I want to work with very large images. I have realized that the substantial part I forget to write. The quotation is 2D array/signal while the image we have is 1D signal so it either is not image or it is just a single strip of image like 1x360px. That's why the formulas differ. But I have yet one more problem to understand the formulas from homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk i,j should be coords in spatial domain but what are k,l? Quite a lot thing to learn still...

Comment: I realized: Although both formulas of FT differs just in capital characters, the meaning of _n_ is different. _n_ means position on horizontal axis, in spacial domain _n_ is time or position, whist in Fourier domain it represents frequency. Very important to remember.

Comment: The FFT is an algorithm for calculating the DFT.

Comment: $k$ and $l$ are the independent variables of the transform.  They are the *spatial frequencies* in your image.

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know: DFT is slower than FFT because FFT mean Fast Fourier Transform _"Even with these computational savings, the ordinary one-dimensional DFT has N2 complexity. This can be reduced to N Log2N if we employ the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) to compute the one-dimensional DFTs. This is a significant improvement, in particular for large images."_ http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm Hence they are not the same.

Comment: What did I say that might be wrong?  I agree 100% with that statement.  The FFT is a method for calculating DFT.  Look:  you are not going to learn Fourier Transforms in these comments.  No one is providing an answer because your task is way too broad.